# TRANSER_FROM_FAILED error when swapping tokens with Web3

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I have a function for swapping from WBNB to a token, and then one function for swapping that token back to WBNB.

They are almost identical, except i change which token to swap from and to, and i use a bnb conversion in the "amountIn" in buy and i dont in the sell.

But i get this error message trying to swap tokens to WBNB with the sell function

```
    raise ContractLogicError(response['error']['message'])
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED
```

```
token = "0x2859e4544C4bB03966803b044A93563Bd2D0DD4D"

def sell(token, amountToSell):
    tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c")  # wbnb contract address
    spend = web3.toChecksumAddress(token)
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
    pancakeswap2_txn = contractbuy.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        amountToSell,
        #web3.toWei(amountToBuy, 'ether'),
        0,
        [spend, tokenToBuy],
        sender_address,
        (int(time.time()) + 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': sender_address,
        #'value': amountToSell,
        #'value': web3.toWei(amountToSell, 'ether'),  # This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn,
                                                   private_key=privatekey)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    transaction_tx = web3.toHex(tx_token)
    print("Sell was succesfull, sold: " + transaction_tx)

    return transaction_tx
```

weirdly enough the buy function works fine, so i cant figure out what i have done wrong in the sell function?
I do have the token example in my wallet and wbnb so what is wrong?

```
def buy(token, amountToBuy):
    spend = web3.toChecksumAddress("0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c")  # wbnb contract address
    tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress(token)
    nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
    pancakeswap2_txn = contractbuy.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens(
        web3.toWei(amountToBuy, 'ether'),
        0,  # set to 0, or specify minimum amount of token you want to receive - consider decimals!!!
        [spend, tokenToBuy],
        sender_address,
        (int(time.time()) + 10000)
    ).buildTransaction({
        'from': sender_address,
        #'value': 1000,
        #'value': web3.toWei(amountToBuy, 'ether'),  # This is the Token(BNB) amount you want to Swap from
        'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': nonce,
    })
    signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn,
                                                   private_key=privatekey)
    tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    transaction_tx = web3.toHex(tx_token)
    print("succesfull, bought: " + transaction_tx)

    return transaction_tx
```

Comment: Hmm, I notice that you have `'gasprice'` defined in there but not `'gas'`. You need to set the gas limit, as well as price, as far as I know. Are you still stuck with this?

Comment: Hey thanks for the asnwer but its like 9 month ago :D i must have fixed cant remeber how :)

Comment: lol yeah, we need more action in the web3 SOF questions for sure.